# How to find the maximum value of the given set?

Tags: metric-spaces

Maximum $\left\{x+y \mid (x,y) \in \overline{B(0,1)}\right\}$ is equal to?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your set consists of the couples $(x,y)$ with $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$.

Clearly we'll want $x$ and $y$ to be positive, so we can rewrite the inequality as 
$$y \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}$$
Since we want to maximize the sum, it seems natural to then try
$$y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$$
We then have to maximize the function 
$$f(x) = x + \sqrt{1-x^2}$$
The derivative is
$$f'(x) = 1 - \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
which is zero when $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Then $y$ is also $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Hence the maximum of the set is 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I draw the plot by wolframalpha :

[image]

Where $x+y=k$, you can see the $y$-axis which is the value $k$.